# Bottom tabBar controller not hiding when I pass to another viewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am making a project where the first MainPage is TabBarController(MainTabController). But then I am passing to another Viewcontroller there is one more tabbetViewControllers(secondTabbedController). And now When I pass to secondTabbedController the tabs of MainTabController are not hiding. There Should be secondTabBarController Items but there tab items of first(MainTabBarController). I guess that it is because of the navigationController and If I delete it it is fixes. But I need this NavigationController. How to fix it ?
[image]
[image]

This is ArticlesViewController that You can find in first image:
[image]

Comment: When you push your secondViewController, try hiding the tabbar view in the viewWillDisappear

Comment: Are you need other tabs on second VC ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:
write this code in first viewcontroller

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    // this will show the tabbar when come back to first viewcontroller
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    // this will hide the tabbar when moved next viewcontroller
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just true this "hidesBottomBarWhenPushed" when you are pushing view controller

```
let objViewController: ProductDetailsViewController? = UIStoryboard.mainStoryboard().instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProductDetailsViewController") as? ProductDetailsViewController
objViewController?.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
navigationController?.pushViewController(objViewController ?? UIViewController(), animated: true)
```

And you can also set this in ViewController XIB "Attribute Inspector" by just clicking "Hide Bottom Bar on Push".